# Angular 5 http POST call not triggering

Tags: angular, http-post, angular5, angular-cli, httpclient

http post call is not triggering from my application. Please check the below code for http post call

```
getTables(): Observable<any[]> {
      return this.http.post<any[]>('http://zltstesasweb01.phs.org:7980/SASBIWS/rest/storedProcesses/Web/hsd3_hsd_pcp_try_111/dataTargets/WEBOUT','<stp><parameters><selFilter>V</selFilter></parameters></stp>',httpOptions);
}
```

Please check below my subscribe method

```
this.constantdataService.getTables().subscribe(dataobj =>{
  console.log(dataobj);
});
```

I am getting the below error in console.

[image]

I am not able to see the post call in my network tab as well

[image]

Comment: don't post a picture of the error. paste the text of the error so people can search this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with 'angular-in-memory-web-api'. In-memory-web-api is blocking the real API call its searching in the localdata services. when I am adding the passThruUnknownUrl: true in configuration of app.module.ts. its started working.

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
  ....
  HttpClientModule,
  ...
  HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
    LocaldatasericeService,{ dataEncapsulation: false,
    passThruUnknownUrl: true }
  )
  ...
]
```